# Database connection on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, yaml

Wow I've been stuck on this one for days. I'm having trouble connecting to database.yml on Heroku. I'm on Cedar and ruby 1.9.2. My dev and test dbs are sqlite3 and the prod db is postgreSQL to cope with Cedar rules.
Here is the code in my ruby script:

```
Rails.env.production? ? (env = "production") : (env = "development")
dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yml'))[env]
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig)
```

All goes well in local but when I push to Heroku, I get:

```
ArgumentError: syntax error on line 17, col 0: `adapter = uri.scheme'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
```

It looks like Heroku doesn't like my database.yml. Here's an overview:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: foo
  port: 5432
  host: foobar.amazonaws.com
  username: foo
  password: bar
```

Comment: did you ever manage to connect to the database?  The answer doesn't seem to really encompass a full solution to connecting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, Heroku **overwrites** your `config/database.yml` with its own Heroku-specific version. That's how Heroku automatically connects your application to its own postgresql databases. To tell Heroku about your own posgresql database, you should set up the correct [config variables](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database) and you might as well **omit** the production database from your the `config/database.yml` in your repository because Heroku will ignore it anyway.

Second, the `config/database.yml` file is an **ERB template** for a YAML file. You **must** first run the file contents through Evaluated Ruby (ERB) before running the the output through YAML.

Comment: OK so if I want to keep Heroku shared DB in production I just delete the three lines above and let Heroku manage the DB itself.
Thanks!

Comment: Correct. If you want to use the Heroku postgres addon (shared & dedicated databases through Heroku), do nothing. If you want to use the Amazon RDS addon, also do nothing. Both of those addons set your application's `DATABASE_URL` config variable, which Heroku's `config/database.yml` parses. If you want to use your own database server, you should set your application's `DATABASE_URL` config variable to point to your own database server, and you should not touch your `config/database.yml`.

Comment: If you want to see what heroku puts in your config/database.yml just do a "heroku run bash" and "cat config/database.yml" ;)

Comment: I have this problem right now too.  line 17 of the config/database.yml file is `adapter = uri.scheme`.  I think the `database.yml` file Heroku is writing is borked.

Comment: See this other SO post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379530/heroku-what-does-writing-config-database-yml-to-read-from-database-url-mean

Comment: I've the same problem, and I don't understand... why in hell connect's to a secret database underground and not to the one i'm telling him... sorry but it doesnt feel well =S

Comment: @yfeldblum Your link to "config variables" is broken. Just thought I'd give you a heads up.